# The sum of the zeros and of the poles in a period parallelogram of an elliptic function f is a period of f

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, elliptic-functions

Let $f$ be an elliptic function with a fundamental set of periods $\omega_1, \omega_2$ (so their ratio is non-real).

Let $S$ be the sum of its poles and zeros inside a period parallelogram.

My attempt:

If $f=\prod_i (z-a_i)^{\alpha_i}$, then $\frac{f'}{f}=\sum_i \frac{\alpha_i}{z-a_i}$ and $\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_c z\frac{f'}{f}(z)dz=\sum a_i\alpha_i=S$

$S$ is a period iff $S=n \omega_1 + m\omega_2$ for some integers $n,m$

Now, $g(z)=\frac{f'}{f}(z)$ is also elliptic so if I picture a parallelogram ABCD, then obviously $\int_{AB+CD} zg(z)dz=\int_{AB} zg(z)dz+\int_{CD} zg(z)dz$

Since ABCD is a period parallelogram, then $z_{CD}=z_{AB}+\omega_1$, and $g$ is elliptic so,

$\int_{AB+CD} zg(z)dz=\int_{AB} zg(z)dz-\int_{AB} (z+\omega_1)g(z)dz=-\omega_1\int_{AB}g(z)dz$

A similar reasoning yields a similar result for BC and $\omega_2$.

My problem is that I can't prove that $\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{AB}g(z)dz$ is an integer. The only things I know about $g$ is that it is elliptic, its integral over the whole parallelogram is $0$ and it counts the difference between the number of zeros and poles inside it. But this is not a closed contour so it is not so useful.

Comment: $\int_A^B g(z)dz = \log f(B)-\log f(A)$ What do know about $\log f(z)$ ? And starting from $f(z) = \prod_i (z-a_i)^{\alpha_i}$ isn't a good idea. You need only that $f$ is meromorphic and $\Lambda$-periodic.

Comment: @reuns So this would be just $0$ ? I was unsure because it said "prove it is a period", instead of simply "prove it is $0$". The starting point was to prove the formula for $S$, I don't know any alternatives

Comment: Oh I get it, $f$ can be defined as $f$ times $e^{2i\pi k}$ any integer $k$, so taking its log and dividing by $2i\pi$ can yield a non-zero integer depending on its definition

Comment: Yes. Take a branch of $\log f(z)$ analytic on the neighborhood of $[A,B]$. Since $f$ is $B-A$ periodic then $\exp(\log f(z+B-A)) = \exp(\log f(z))$ and $\log f(B) = \log f(A)+2i \pi k$ for some integer $k$. Then do the same with $[B,C]$ and you are done.